# How to avoid huge if-else checking when trying to find a value determined by multiple parameters?

Tags: c#, refactoring

My function has 1 job: return a simple `int` index. However, in order to "calculate" that index, it takes into consideration a few parameters (3 in my case, but for simplicity I will use 2 parameters in this example). My function looks something like this:

```
int calculateIndex(int param1, int param2)
```

Now, how does it currently do the job? It does so in "layers". Firstly it checks what value is `param1`. Once it established that, it starts checking what value is `param2` and so on. Like so:

```
if(param1 == 0)
{
    if(param2 == 0)
    {
        // Return some value.
    }
    else if(param2 == 1)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
else if(param1 == 1)
{
    if(param2 == 3)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
else
{
    if(param2 == 4)
    {

    }
    else if(param2 == 5)
    {

    }
    else if(param2 == 6)
    {

    }
    else if(param2 == 7)
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
}
```

What is important to notice is that each case of `param1` can have arbitrary number of `if-elses` for `param2`. For example, if `param1` is 0, there will be 3 cases which `param2` can be. However, if `param1` is 1, `param2` has 2 cases, it is either `3` or `else`.

If none of this made sense, let me give you an actual example. Consider the following function:

```
void uselessFunction(int biome, int element)
```

`uselessFunction` takes `biome` and `element` indexes as parameters and prints appropriate message based on input.

```
// Forest, Grass etc. are integer constants.

if(biome == Forest)
{
    if(element == Grass)
    {
        print("There is grass in the forest.");
    }
    else if(element == Water)
    {
        print("There is water in the forest.");
    }
    else
    {
        print("Given element is invalid for this biome.");
    }
}
else if(biome == Desert)
{
    if(element == Sand)
    {
        print("There is sand in the desert.");
    }
    else
    {
        print("Given element is invalid for this biome.");
    }
}
else
{
    print("Given biome is invalid.");
}
```

Now, this example is fairly short, but as you can see, with only 2 biomes and a few blocks, this code is pretty long already. Imagine the case of 20 biomes, with every biome having 10-15 blocks that can appear on them. This causes incredibly long function that does a simple task and I need a better way of designing that function. How?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The technique you want is called "table-driven programming".  You establish a series of "tables" that contain the data you're interested in, and then instead of doing an if-else series, you do a table lookup.

Since your element tables are just yes-no decisions, you don't even need a dictionary; just a set will do:

```
var biomeTable = new Dictionary<Biome, HashSet<Element>>()
{
  { Forest, new HashSet<Element>() { Grass, Water }},
  { Desert, new HashSet<Element>() { Sand }}
};
```

And now your code is:

```
if (biomeTable.ContainsKey(biome)) 
{
  if (biomeTable[biome].Contains(element))
    Console.WriteLine($"The {biome} contains {element}.");
  else
    Console.WriteLine($"The {biome} does not contain {element}.");
} 
else
   Console.WriteLine($"Invalid biome {biome}.");
```

See how that goes?  The logic is just two if-thens, not as many as there are biome/element combinations.  The information goes in the data structure, not in the structure of the code.

This way you can put the biomes and elements into a configuration file and parse them out of the file, building up the dictionary and sets dynamically if you like.

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you Eric!

Answer (score 2):

You couple use a [Tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.tuple?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) as compound key in a Dictionary of conditions.

In the below example, the value of each Dictionary item is a string (as in your example, the message is the only differentiating factor).

However, it could also be a type or instance of a type which implements an interface, for example IBiomeElementLogic, with a different implementation for each key.

This would be a form of [Inversion of Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control).

```
enum Biome
{
    Forest = 1,
    Desert = 2
}

enum Element
{
    Grass = 1,
    Water = 2,
    Sand = 3
}

static readonly Dictionary<(Biome, Element), string> Conditions = new Dictionary<(Biome, Element), string>
{
    { (Biome.Forest, Element.Grass) , "There is grass in the forest." },
    { (Biome.Forest, Element.Water) , "There is water in the forest." },
    { (Biome.Desert, Element.Sand) , "There is sand in the desert." }
};

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    UselessFunction(Biome.Forest, Element.Grass);
    UselessFunction(Biome.Forest, Element.Water);
    UselessFunction(Biome.Forest, (Element)100);
    UselessFunction(Biome.Desert, Element.Sand);
    UselessFunction(Biome.Desert, (Element)100);
    UselessFunction((Biome)100, Element.Grass);

    Console.Read();
}

static void UselessFunction(Biome biome, Element element)
{
    var key = (biome, element);

    if (Conditions.ContainsKey(key))
    {
        Print(Conditions[key]);
    }
    else if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(Biome), biome))
    {
        Print("Given element is invalid for this biome.");
    }
    else
    {
        Print("Given biome is invalid.");
    }
}

static void Print(string message)
{
    Console.WriteLine(message);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This technique will help you simplify the logic in the method.

```
class BiomeElement
{
    public BiomeElement(int biome, int element)
    {
        Biome = biome;
        Element = element;
    }

    public int Biome { get; }
    public int Element { get; }

    public bool IsForestGrass { get { return Biome == 1 && Element == 1; } }
    public bool IsForestWater { get { return Biome == 1 && Element == 2; } }
}
```